Organizing pages into different categories/sections
The solutions I found seem a little inelegant and involve using additional plugins to use post categories for evergreen pages, which I think would make a mess of the blog section and confuse the posts chronology.
I am looking to have website sections that are clearly visible in the URL, for example:
mywebsite.com/dogs
mywebsite.com/dogs/why-are-dogs-loyal
mywebsite.com/shoes
mywebsite.com/shoes/best-barefoot-shoe-brands

I am also looking to have parent and child pages, as I will have some guides that are split within a number of siblings and need a parent page.
How can I have a website with clear different sections as above in a meaningful way? This seems pretty relevant from an SEO point of view and for website navigability.

Sorry, I'm probably not understanding this, but what you listed above is how the basic WP page hierarchy works.  You make a page called 'Dogs' with a slug that is /dogs/ then you make a page called 'Why are dogs loyal' with a slug that is /why-are-dogs-loyal/, then assign 'Dogs' as the parent page and the full slug becomes /dogs/why-are-dogs-loyal/

Wow I guess I'm a total noob. :D Yes this is what I needed. I'll need to play with it a little then.

Glad I could help. Best of luck.  :-)
